# If Microsoft is pushing systemd so hard, then why do I restart my services in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS WSL using System V?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux, system-v

I had to restart my apache2 server in WSL yesterday, and I was surprised that I couldn't use `systemctl` like I do on Ubuntu; instead having to revert to `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

But I thought Lennart Poettering had Microsoft ties; what's going on here?

Comment: “I thought Lennart Poettering had Microsoft ties” — what made you think that?

Comment: @StephenKitt Probably the hatred directed towards him: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennart_Poettering#Controversies

Comment: @StephenKitt But maybe that's just for his breaking of the Linux Philosophy, and I just thought it was Microsoft.

Comment: I don’t see any reference to Microsoft there... Lots of hatred is directed at Microsoft, and lots at Lennart, but that doesn’t mean they have ties ;-).

Comment: Right - believe it or not, it's entirely possible for a subset of the Linux community to take issue with software and architecture decisions without any help from Microsoft at all! ;-)

Comment: Probably correctly closed as opinion-based, but I think you could edit it (if you want) to get it on-topic.

Comment: Yup, @NotTheDr01ds’ answer is useful, and you could re-phrase your question to turn it into an on-topic question leading to that answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of questions and statements between the title and question to address:

> If Microsoft is pushing systemd so hard
>
> I thought Lennart Poettering had Microsoft ties

As pointed out in the comments, there's just no relation between Microsoft and Poettering, nor between Microsoft and Systemd.

> I was surprised that I couldn't use `systemctl` like I do on Ubuntu; instead having to revert to sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

That's to be expected under WSL.  One of the "missing pieces" in WSL continues to be support for alternative PID1 supervisors (a.k.a. Systemd, although to be fair there are a few others).

You'll find a number of issues in the WSL github repo around this, but I believe the two main ones are:

- [Blockers for systemd?](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/994)
- [systemctl doesn't work](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1579)

The problem, at its core, is that WSL uses its own `/init` process to bootstrap much of the interop between Windows and Linux/WSL.  I've made a partial list in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328686/1165986).

Systemd's monolithic design (at least in this regard) requires that it be PID1 for *any* and all of its functionality to work.

It's *possible* with WSL2 to start a new PID namespace with Systemd as PID1, enter that namespace, and then have `systemctl` functionality.  However, there are a lot of caveats that come with it.

To see this in practice (not for "normal use"), though:

```
sudo -b unshare --pid --fork --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target
# Wait 10-20 seconds for things to start up
sudo -E nsenter --all -t $(pgrep -xo systemd) runuser -P -l $USER -c "exec $SHELL"
```

You should be able to start Apache through `systemctl`.

Note that this will cause multiple *other* issues, though:

- You won't be able to run Windows executables since Systemd removes the WSL `binfmt_misc` handler.
- The Windows path won't be appended to the WSL2/Linux path.
- WSLg won't work in Windows 11 since `systemd-tmpfiles` removes the socket
- And others

There are third-party scripts (Genie, WSL2Hacks, and more) that are designed to get WSL2 and Systemd working together, but you *really* don't need them for the most part.

For most tasks, as you've seen, you can simply use the `init.d` scripts, if they are available in your distribution.  You might also consider an alternative process supervisor such as Supervisord that doesn't require that it be PID1.  It can even be set to boot automatically in Windows 11 and run any startup tasks you need.

Personally, I've been experimenting with non-Systemd distributions under WSL.  Artix (an Arch-based distribution) with the `dinit` process supervisor seems fairly promising so far.