# New to WSL, trying to install Debian with GUI

Tags: debian, upgrade, gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a Linux old-timer, less familiar with Windows, although I've been using Windows since it was MS-DOS.

I just bought a new Windows 11 computer and am trying to install Debian in the WSL with GUI capabilities. I managed to install Debian with WSL version 2. What I got was mainly just a bash shell. I tried to follow Microsoft's advice and `apt install gedit -y`, but I got an error message (`package gedit not found`).

In another article, I read that it was necessary to install 'lsb-release', but again, when trying to install lsb-release, it wasn't found.

How do I find these elusive software tools for Debian in WSL? I have tried everything I can think of, but I don't want to, say, destroy my Windows Installation.

Pictures of Debian with GUI in WSL show colorful tableaux with easy-to-find software. How can I join the fun?

Comment: Hi, Bryan, did you searched the internet about how to install it? I think you may find interesting to look https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps if you have already did.Also, https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-debian-on-windows-wsl/ , https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Microsoft/Windows/SubsystemForLinux and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install  may help.

Comment: You may find this useful as well [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/1393169#1393169)

Comment: @hophop Ironically, the example that the OP is using comes directly from the Microsoft doc you linked on GUI apps, so I'm fairly sure they've seen it (since they reference it as "Microsoft's advice") ;-)

Comment: @steeldriver Probably not all that useful for this particular case.  The OP is already on Windows 11, so it should "just work" once they get past the "normal" `apt update` hurdle.  I'll be surprised if it doesn't, anyway.  But I've been wrong before :-)

Answer (score 2):

This *should* be fairly straightforward, at least for starters.  I've reproduced it on a fresh Debian install on WSL.  While I can provide a solution for the installation, please read to the end for caveats.

After a fresh install:

```
$ sudo apt install gedit -y
E: Unable to locate package gedit
```

The reason for this is that most WSL distributions (like Docker images) do not come with populated repo caches to save on bandwidth.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install gedit -y
```

Works (mostly) as expected at that point.

Also recommended, since this is a fresh install of course, is:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

---

##### Caveats

Note that `gedit`, being Gnome software, has a high level of dependency on D-Bus and other services which aren't running by default under WSL.  D-Bus is normally started by Systemd units and processes on Debian (and most other distributions), but Systemd isn't normally supported under WSL (a separate topic, really, and one that I've already [provided another answer on today](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/696554/432493)).

When you run `gedit` above, you'll end up with some degraded functionality without D-bus, and some of the supporting services won't start.  You'll get some errors, and *all* that will be running is `gedit`.  Here's the `ps -eH` from a separate session looking at the state:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 init
    7 ?        00:00:00   init
    8 ?        00:00:00     init
    9 pts/0    00:00:00       bash
   11 pts/0    00:00:00         gedit
   20 ?        00:00:00   init
   21 ?        00:00:00     init
   22 pts/1    00:00:00       bash
   28 pts/1    00:00:00         ps
   29 pts/1    00:00:00         bash
```

While I haven't tested this extensively, it looks like this is solvable for `gedit`, at least by installing:

```
sudo apt install dbus-x11
```

Running `gedit` will then auto-launch D-bus using `dbus-launch`.  You can see that a number of dependent services are also started as a result:

```
     UID   PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
       0     1     0  0 22:03 ?        Sl     0:00 /init
       0     7     1  0 22:03 ?        Ss     0:00   /init
       0     8     7  0 22:03 ?        S      0:00     /init
    1000     9     8  0 22:03 pts/0    Ss     0:00       -bash
    1000    11     9  0 22:03 pts/0    Sl+    0:00         gedit
    1000    16     8  0 22:03 pts/0    S+     0:00       dbus-launch --autolaunch=51f357b828e646fc889cfee60effb53c --binary-syntax --close-stderr
    1000    17     8  0 22:03 ?        Ss     0:00       /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog-only --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
    1000    23     8  0 22:03 ?        Sl     0:00       /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher
    1000    28    23  0 22:03 ?        S      0:00         /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
    1000    30     8  0 22:03 ?        Sl     0:00       /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
    1000    35     8  0 22:03 ?        Sl     0:00       /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
       0    44    35  0 22:03 ?        Ss     0:00         fusermount -o rw,nosuid,nodev,fsname=portal,auto_unmount,subtype=portal -- /mnt/wslg/runtime-dir/doc
    1000    39     8  0 22:03 ?        Sl     0:00       /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
    1000    49     8  0 22:03 ?        Sl     0:00       /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
    1000    55     8  0 22:03 ?        Sl     0:00       /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
    1000    59     8  0 22:03 ?        Sl     0:00       /usr/libexec/dconf-service
       0    68     1  0 22:03 ?        Ss     0:00   /init
       0    69    68  0 22:03 ?        S      0:00     /init
    1000    70    69  0 22:03 pts/1    Ss     0:00       -bash
    1000    93    70  0 22:05 pts/1    R+     0:00         ps n -efH
    1000    94    70  0 22:05 pts/1    D+     0:00         -bash
```

Note that there may still be additional functionality in Gnome and gedit that expects additional services or packages that would normally be started installed under a full "Desktop" Debian, or that would be started by Systemd.

For instance, Trash functionality in `gedit` is provided by `gio` and `gvfs`, neither of which are installed by default in WSL.  Without those, you'll get "Operation Not Supported" if you try to examine the Trash in `gedit`.

To resolve *that*:

```
sudo apt install gvfs libglib2.0-bin
```

---

##### And ... one more thing

Well, first of all (last of all?), Welcome to WSL.  Since you mention previous Linux experience, one thing that's important to understand about WSL is that it is *not* like a physical (or even virtual) machine.  When you are running Debian inside WSL, it's really running in its own PID namespace *inside* a virtual machine that you can't access (the "Virtual Machine Platform" feature in Windows).  It's more like a distribution running in a Docker container.

Most of the differences you'll come across between "normal" Linux and WSL stem from this.  No shutdown/reboot, no Systemd, the fact that the networking is provided by Windows (not Linux) and you don't have much control over it, etc. etc.